# ssh remote command as different user

Tags: linux, ssh, command

Why does the `awk` portion of this command not get processed. It works when I run this directly as `user1`.

```
[zimmerman@SERVER1 check]# su  user1 -c "ssh -i /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa -q user1@SERVER2 df -h /dir1/dir2 | awk '{print $5}'"

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdf1            1008G  204M  957G   1% /dir1/dir2
```

Comment: provide minimal example what does not work, what you get and what you expect. When you combine `su`, `ssh` and pipes into long command and does not tell what you want/what is the question, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 
When I run:
su  user1 -c "ssh -i /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa -q user1@SERVER2 df -h /dir1/dir2 | awk '{print $5}'"

I get as output:
/dev/sdf1            1008G  204M  957G   1% /dir1/dir2

Instead of just 1% which is what is expected from addition of the awk command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you combine all these stuff together, you need to make sure you escape all the important characters that you don't want to evaluate now, but later one. The `$` is a good example of that.

```
$ su user1 -c "ssh -i [...] -q user1@SERVER2 df -h /dir1/dir2 | awk '{print $5}'"
```

evaluates the `$5` in the current bash, which is what you don't want. You can see it, if you run simply

```
$ echo "ssh -i [...] -q user1@SERVER2 df -h /dir1/dir2 | awk '{print $5}'"
ssh -i [...] -q user1@SERVER2 df -h /dir1/dir2 | awk '{print }'
```

So to fix it, you need to escape the `$` sign, such as

```
$ echo "ssh -i [...] -q user1@SERVER2 df -h /dir1/dir2 | awk '{print \$5}'"
ssh -i [...] -q user1@SERVER2 df -h /dir1/dir2 | awk '{print $5}'
```

**TL;DR**: so the final commandline you should use is

```
su  user1 -c "ssh -i /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa -q user1@SERVER2 df -h /dir1/dir2 | awk '{print \$5}'"
```